# Counting Substrings: In a given text, find the number of substrings that start with an $A$ and end with a $B$.

Tags: algorithms

For Example, there are four such substrings in $CABAAXBYA$.

The original brute force algorithm that I used was, Using an outer for loop, whenever I encounter an $A$, I go inside another for loop to check if there's a $B$ present or not. If a $B$ is found, I increment the count. Finally, the value stored in the count variable yields the required result.

I came across a point while reading about String matching algorithms, when you traverse right to left rather than left to right, your algorithm is more efficient but here the substring isn't given as a parameter to the function that you would be using to compute the required value.

My question is if I traverse the string from right to left instead of left to right, will it make my algorithm more efficient in any case?

Answer (score 0):

Scan the string from left to right. Every time you encounter an $A$, increment a counter. Every time you encounter a $B$, the value of the counter tells you how many substrings starting with an $A$ end at that particular $B$, so add the value to a running total. By the end of the string, the running total gives you the answer.